# Difference between `adb pair` and `adb connect`?

Tags: android, adb

What's the difference between `adb pair …` and `adb connect …`? (When used to communicate with a device that's made itself available for debugging over Wi-Fi.)

The help page says:

- `adb connect`: "connect to a device via TCP/IP"
- `adb pair`: "pair with a device for secure TCP/IP communication"

From this is sounds like `pair` is better but … how? What are the pros and cons? (Aside from only being available on Android 11+ devices.)

Comment: Did some more investigation: on the phones I have access to, I need `pair` for Android 11 devices, but `connect` otherwise. However, Wear devices with Android 11 need `connect`. So, not sure if "Wear" is the only exception to the Android >= 11 rule or whether it can vary by OEM.

Answer (score 2):

`adb pair` is used for wifi pairing your device with Android >= 11, while `adb connect` can be used to connect directly to a device with Android <11 over wifi.

From the [documentation for wifi pairing with Android >= 11](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+) it says:

> To use wireless debugging, you must pair your device to your workstation using a QR Code or a pairing code.

If your phone uses Android <11 then you can use the `connect` command and the steps from the [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless)

Comment: No. For a directly via USB connected device you don't need `adb connect`. This command connects to a device via IP & TCP.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer.